# Using Google OR-Tools, CP-SAT, how do you make the optimization routine do a more thorough search? [Solved]

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I'm using Google OR-Tools' CP-SAT to make a scheduling optimizer in C#. I used the examples,
[ShiftSchedulingSat](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/dotnet/ShiftSchedulingSat.cs) and [NursesSat](https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling) as examples. My code is conceptually similar to ShiftSchedulingSat, in that I built a series of boolean requirements, as well as a list of terms with a bool * penalty in an array to be optimized, just as the obj in that example.

Similar to the example, I have several places where there is both a hard and soft requirement. I tried setting the hard requirement high, and the soft requirement low, to optimize on the value. The code returns within a second or two with a 'feasible' answer, but not optimal. I tried incrementally decrementing my hard requirement to manually find the lower bound. When it is + 1 or 2 of the lower bound I found, I get the 'optimal' answer; the soft requirement works! I don't understand in this model why it won't find the 'optimal' answer when the hard limits are increased. The code always returns in 1-2 seconds. Is there any way to make it look harder when searching for optimal?

I have tried running the above with many permutations on the StringParameters, including:

```
"num_search_workers:8, max_time_in_seconds:60";
"num_search_workers:8";  
"linearization_level:2, enumerate_all_solutions:true"
```

and pretty much every permutation of these options. I noticed that enumerate_all_solutions will cause the run time to increase profoundly, but always seems to stop around 29.9 seconds, even with the max_time_in_seconds set longer. I'm wondering if there's a bug that's causing it to stop searching at 30 seconds even with that option set. I have run the code without any optimization function, similar to the NursesSat example, and it will easily run for several minutes to enumerate 10 solutions, so I'm confused why adding optimization causes it to exit so quickly.

My thoughts are that there may be a bug causing it to timeout prematurely, there may be separate settings for the optimizing routine, which seems to be a separate linear optimization step, or that the linear optimization is getting caught in local minima and giving up easily.

Edit:

Here's relevent log output:
[Log output with the HardMax set to 4](https://pastebin.com/HDRPcdGq)
[Log output with the HardMax set to 5](https://pastebin.com/nbXcKDE9)

I kept everything in my model same except modifying my hardmax of one constraint. The softmax was left the same to run the optimizer over. When the hardmax is set to 5, the optimizer achieves an output for the value in question of [ 2,4,4,4,4,4,4 ], but when I lower the hardmax to 4, the optimizer achieves an output of [ 2,3,3,3,3,3,3 ].

Looking at the logs, I can see that the linear optimizer is searching a lot more branch points when the hardmax is only 4, and it doesn't appear to generate any solutions at all when the hardmax is 5:

```
Search stats        Bools  Conflicts  Branches  Restarts  BoolPropag  IntegerPropag
     'default_lp':  2'372        450     6'584     4'746      42'203         36'841
          'no_lp':  2'372    207'791   637'173     6'640  25'221'620      4'908'163
         'max_lp':  2'372          0     5'180     4'744      21'870         30'859
           'core':  2'385    366'860   547'295     4'751  27'026'157      4'990'961
  'reduced_costs':  2'388          4     4'975     4'744      21'754         30'520
   'pseudo_costs':  2'385         10     5'576     4'745      23'418         33'435

LNS stats           Improv/Calls  Closed  Difficulty  TimeLimit
      'rins/rens':         41/41     46%        0.69       0.10
    'rnd_var_lns':           0/0      0%        0.50       0.10
    'rnd_cst_lns':           0/0      0%        0.50       0.10
  'graph_var_lns':           0/0      0%        0.50       0.10
  'graph_arc_lns':           0/0      0%        0.50       0.10
  'graph_cst_lns':           0/0      0%        0.50       0.10
  'graph_dec_lns':           0/0      0%        0.50       0.10

...

Solution repositories    Added  Queried  Ignored  Synchro
  'feasible solutions':      1        0        0        1  <---
        'lp solutions':     14        3        0        8  <---
                'pump':     40       38
```

vs

```
Search stats        Bools  Conflicts  Branches  Restarts  BoolPropag  IntegerPropag
     'default_lp':  2'715          0         0         0           0              2
          'no_lp':  2'715          0     3'972     3'972      21'243         28'774
         'max_lp':  2'715          0         0         0           0              1
           'core':  2'728          0     3'958     3'958      21'171         28'680
  'reduced_costs':  2'715          0     5'430     5'430      21'640         30'669
   'pseudo_costs':  2'715          0       576       576       2'669          3'497

...

Solution repositories    Added  Queried  Ignored  Synchro
  'feasible solutions':      1        0        0        1
        'lp solutions':      0        0        0        0
                'pump':      0        0
```

Gah!!! Nevermind...
Just noticed this in the log.

> Stop search after 1 solutions <--

I left the stop code from the nurse solution active and it was stopping the search prematurely. I've been grinding on this for days, but at least now I have a better knowledge of how CP-SAT works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too abstract.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- you should enable logging to follow what the solver is doing
- enumerate_all_solutions disable all parallelism
- the solver only does what you tell him to do. If there is a primary and a secundary objective. Tell the solver so. You can for instance solve with the first objective, add a constraint bound on the first objective, then solve with the second objective.

Comment: "enumerate_all_solutions disable all parallelism"
I got this from other stackoverflows. I understand from the nurse example that you can calculate all of the feasible possibilities, and that's what this option enables. Can you explain what it does if you have a minimize or maximize objective such as the shift scheduling example? It makes the code take longer to execute for sure, but I'm not sure if it has any value. I can't find documentation how the constraint model and linear optimization models are interacting.

Comment: "solve with the first objective, add a constraint bound on the first objective, then solve with the second objective."
Yes, exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm on trying to solve the first objective with optimization, but I can't get the optimizer to work

Comment: define 'does not work'. What is the status returned by the solve() function. What does the objective looks like ? Is it optimized ? Can you post the log , attach the model ?

Comment: Please don't waste any more of your time looking at this. It was a stupid bug in my code. I'm terribly sorry for using any of your time, and I'm extremely grateful to you and the google team for this tool.